# Compiling C++ files using MEX

Tags: matlab, mex

I want to use MEX for compiling C\C++ files on MATLAB. I tried `mex -setup` first then `mex xyz.cpp`. But I am still getting error

> E:\MATLAB~1\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'xyz.cpp' failed.

When typing this command

```
mex -v mexDiscreteFlow.cpp BPFlow.cpp Stochastic.cpp
```

I get the following output

> This is mex, Copyright 1984-2007 The MathWorks, Inc.
>
> -> Default options filename found in C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2008b 
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------
>   ->    Options file           = C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2008b\mexopts.bat
>         MATLAB                 = E:\MATLAB~1
>   ->    COMPILER               = lcc
>   ->    Compiler flags:
>            COMPFLAGS           = -c -Zp8 -I"E:\MATLAB~1\sys\lcc\include" -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -noregistrylookup
>            OPTIMFLAGS          = -DNDEBUG
>            DEBUGFLAGS          = -g4
>            arguments           =
>            Name switch         = -Fo
>   ->    Pre-linking commands   =
>   ->    LINKER                 = lcclnk
>   ->    Link directives:
>            LINKFLAGS           =  -tmpdir "." -dll "E:\MATLAB~1\extern\lib\win32\lcc\mexFunction.def" -L"E:\MATLAB~1\sys\lcc\lib" -libpath "E:\MATLAB~1\extern\lib\win32\lcc" "C:\USERS\abc\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_JT~1\templib2.obj"
>            LINKDEBUGFLAGS      =
>            LINKFLAGSPOST       = libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib
>            Name directive      = -o "mexDiscreteFlow.mexw32"
>            File link directive =
>            Lib. link directive =
>            Rsp file indicator  = @
>   ->    Resource Compiler      = lrc -I"E:\MATLAB~1\sys\lcc\include" -noregistrylookup -fo"mexversion.res"
>   ->    Resource Linker        =
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------
>
> --> lcc  -c -Zp8 -I"E:\MATLAB~1\sys\lcc\include" -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -noregistrylookup -FoC:\USERS\abc\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_JT~1\mexDiscreteFlow.obj -IE:\MATLAB~1\extern\include -IE:\MATLAB~1\simulink\include -DNDEBUG -DMX_COMPAT_32 C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp
>
> lcc preprocessor error: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\ImageProcessing.h:7 C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\Image.h:7 C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp:3 Could not find include file 
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 7  syntax error; found `<' expecting`;'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 7  skipping `<'
>
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 7  syntax error; found`T' expecting `;'
>
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 7  syntax error; found`>' expecting `;'
>
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 7  skipping`>'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 8  syntax error; found `*' expecting`)'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 8  skipping `*'`pBuffer'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 10  undeclared identifier `pBuffer'
>
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11  undeclared identifier`delete'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11  illegal expression
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11  syntax error; found `pBuffer' expecting`]'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11  type error: pointer expected
>   Warning C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11  Statement has no effect
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11  syntax error; found `pBuffer' expecting`;'
>   Warning C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11  Statement has no effect
>   Warning C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 11   possible usage of delete before   definition
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 15  syntax error; found `<' expecting`;'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 15  skipping `<'
>
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 15  syntax error; found`T' expecting `;'
>
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 15  syntax error; found`>' expecting `;'
>
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 15  skipping`>'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 16  syntax error; found `*' expecting`)'
>   Error C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\mexDiscreteFlow.cpp: C:\USERS\abc\DOWNLO~1\RELEASE\RELEASE\MEX\project.h: 16  too many errors
>
> E:\MATLAB~1\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'mexDiscreteFlow.cpp' failed.
>
> ??? Error using ==> mex at 213
>   Unable to complete successfully.

Can anyone offer some suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Try compiling without running your C++ compiler from within Matlab. That should help you isolate the problem.

Comment: I guess you run `mex -setup` instead of mex-setup, right?

Comment: @drodbar: yes.. i will edit it.

Comment: Try 'mex -v xyz.cpp' and provide the full output. There must be another error (other than "compile failed") that would give an indication of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lcc is the **C** compiler shipped with Matlab, but you are trying to compile a **C++** file.
You need to run mex -setup again and choose a C++ compiler (but first get a C++ compiler, if you don't already have one)

Comment: it's best using visual studio's compiler on windows platforms.